# Highcharts Stacked Columns Labels on Top

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image: Stacked column chart with labels]

I want to have all the stacked column labels at the top on top of each other. 
[image]

Is this possible. I tried various combos, such as moving the labels up via padding but this isnt dynamic and wont work if the values of the category change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One options is to simply loop over your data in the formatter for your stack labels. For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k95d0p8b/)):

```
yAxis: {
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        y: -30,
        formatter: function() {
          const series = this.axis.chart.series
          const values = [];

          for(let i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
            values.push(series[i].yData[this.x]);
          }

            return values.join("<br>");
        },
    }
}
```

Do note that you might have to do some kind of `y` offset (as in the example) to make it appear on top when using `<br>` as your separator value.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I wanted!

Comment: Is it possible to make each one of those numbers different color? If so how would I do this. I can make them all a different color but not sure how to control them individually.

Comment: @Alex [heres a quick example](https://jsfiddle.net/0rj7d3bg/). You need `useHTML` and then some HTML to actually color it.

Comment: Last question, you been so great! Sooo when I hide a series, it hides it and all but how do I make the formatter know that I'm hiding a series and not all that series' value to the label?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure I understand, but do you mean something like `if(series[i].visible)`...? [See this example](https://jsfiddle.net/a7vyt30z/)

Comment: Yess that solved my problem, I didnt know where to look for all the possible properties for series[i]. Thanks so much!